# Getting error when trying to Start Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, redhat, yum

I am in the process of installing Jenkins on a clean RHEL 8 server (Red Hat). These are the steps I took.

Adding Jenkins Repository and import public key

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key
```

Validate Repo

```
yum repolist
```

Install Jenkins

```
yum install jenkins
```

Problem arises when I try to start the service using this command

```
systemctl start jenkins
```

I get this error:

```
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov jenkins[596247]: Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov jenkins[596247]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: winstone.Launcher
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov jenkins[596247]:         at executable.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov jenkins[596247]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: winstone.Launcher
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov jenkins[596247]:         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov jenkins[596247]:         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov jenkins[596247]:         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov jenkins[596247]:         at executable.Main.main(Main.java:288)
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 22 18:04:04 v2626umcth960.rtord.epa.gov systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Weird thing is I can run Jenkins from the command line just using the command "jenkins" as "dzdo su -", so at least I know Java 17 doesn't appear to be the issue. The caveat to running in command line is that it doesn't appear to be reading the configuration file where I changed the http running port from 8080 to 8082.

As an Addendum the only change that was made in for config was this:

```
## Type:        integer(0:65535)
## Default:     8080
## ServiceRestart: jenkins
#
# Port Jenkins is listening on.
# Set to -1 to disable
#
JENKINS_PORT="8082"
```

Where I changed the port from "" to "8082"

Also I ran this command and this is the result for permission

```
[root@v2626umcth960 gdss]# ls -l /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
-rw-------. 1 root root 3503 Aug 21 15:30 /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

Comment: Your installation steps are all correct. You can get more logs using `sudo journalctl -u jenkins`. Hopefully there is something there that describes the problem better. Also, try removing the configuration you added and running it vanilla to see if the config file is the issue.